# Assigning to char *[50]?

Tags: c, arrays, char

This is probably very simple, but I am trying to make something with has a variable defined like this:

```
char *temp[50];
```

And to change it I am doing things like:

```
strcpy(temp[1],"Hi");
```

However this segmentation faults.
I tried `&temp[1]`, however this does not work. Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Edit: after reading comments and answers, I have decided to post some more information.

What I am trying to do is have 50 chars (so I could put char *temp1, char *temp2, etc) only in one, so it would go from char *temp1, char *temp2, etc to char *temp[50]

Comment: You should probably describe the problem you're trying to solve rather than just posting (presumably wrong) code and saying that you want "something like this". What the correct code should look like depends on what you're trying to do!

Comment: @user1150512 What are you trying for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use malloc() or fixed 2d array(actually 1d).

```
 char temp[10][50]={0};

 strcpy(temp[1],"Hi");

 printf("%s", temp[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You only created an array of pointers that point to nothing in particular. You need to assign memory to `temp[1]`, possibly via `malloc`, *before `strcpy`*.

```
temp[1] = malloc(3); /* Hi\0 */
```

Answer (score 1):

The segfault occurs because `temp[1]` initially points nowhere(*). Do

```
temp[1] = malloc(sizeof("Hi"));
// check for errors
strcpy(temp[1], "Hi");
```

or, on a POSIX platform

```
temp[1] = strdup("Hi");
```

Don't forget to `free` the results of `malloc` and/or `strdup`!

(*) The pointers are either all `NULL` when `temp` is `static` or global, or contain random garbage.

Comment: Oh no, don't encourage using `strdup`. You already have a memory leak.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: there's only a memory leak if the OP forgets to `free`. What's wrong with `strdup`?

Comment: It messes up the rule "one `free` for every `malloc`" and sneakily allocates dynamic memory. It's too easy to forget to free it, and the OP probably doesn't know enough to even use `free` on `malloc`ed memory in the first place.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: that rule is fuzzy anyway; in practical settings, there are more functions than just `malloc` that do allocation. I don't mind that, as long as they all document if and how deallocation should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You declare array of pointers. You need to allocate the memory either on stack:

```
temp[1] = "Hi";
```

or on heap:

```
temp[1] = malloc(sizeof("Hi"));
```

Or you perhaps you wanted do declare only char array:

```
char temp[50];
```